# Accessing test&target API / calling saveCampaign/createCampaign API

Tags: analytics, aem

I am trying to access saveCampaign API for testing purpose.

I followed the instructions provided, formed URL to create a plain campaign with URL  :

***https://testandtarget.omniture.com/api?client=user&email=user1@acme.com&password=pword&version=1&operation=saveCampaign&thirdPartyId=extID501&version=1&campaign=NNNNCampaign-Name***

ofcourse, by editing proper email,clientID and password.

I get below mentioned error message :

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<error>
<message> A generic Exception has occurred. </message>
<code> 500 </code>
</error>
```

However the operation listCampaign works fine and returns a list of campaigns.

It would be a great help if someone could help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The campaign parameter needs to contain a valid XML representation of the campaign you want to create/save as stated in the Test&Target's API docs. The error message you get points to a problem parsing the campaign XML parameter which is most likely caused by sending invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

the XML document was not valid.

I modified it and created offer and could crate campaign.
thanks florin for pointing me in correct direction